# ExpressJS: Is it possible to share variables between different routing functions for the same route?

Tags: node.js, express

While getting and processing query parameters within different routing functions, it is necessary to define the same thing within each routing function.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next){

    var processed_query = process_function(req.query); 
    //do some thing based on the query string 
    console.log(processed_query);
    next();
}, function(req, res, next){
   var processed_query = process_function(req.query); //this needs to be defined again
   //do some different thing based on the query string 
    res.write(JSON.stringify(processed_query));
});
```

While it is understandable to do it this way because the functions' scopes are different, it seems a bit superfluous and against the general rule of ***don't repeat yourself*** to have to repeatedly define the same variable `var processed_query = process_function(req.query);` for the exact same `req.` Is there a (better) way of doing it just once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your calcuated variable in some property of req object. E.g.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    var processed_query = process_function(req.query); 
    //do some thing based on the query string 
    console.log(processed_query);
    req.processed_query = processed_query;
    next();
}, function(req, res, next){
   var processed_query = req.processed_query; 
   //do some different thing based on the query string 
    res.write(JSON.stringify(processed_query));
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea; I can use the req object itself; thanks!